# Remote Pull via Git Hook takes a really long time

Tags: git, version-control, githooks

Git responds great on our development server, but when we do a git push, a git hook tells the live server to do a git pull to publish everything that has been pushed on the development server in that one step.  Our problem is, that git hook takes approximately 45 seconds to do a git pull from the live server, but when we manually do a git pull on the live server it is nearly instantaneous.

With debugging turned on for timestamps, this is an example of what happens:

```
$ git push
Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Writing objects: 100% (5/5), 435 bytes | 217.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 5 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Checking connectivity: 5, done.
remote: Debug: set branch start @ Wed, Sep  6, 2017 10:12:28 PM
remote: Debug: set branch end @ Wed, Sep  6, 2017 10:12:28 PM
remote: GIT pull master on live server...
remote: Debug: cd start @ Wed, Sep  6, 2017 10:12:28 PM
remote: Debug: cd end @ Wed, Sep  6, 2017 10:12:28 PM
remote: Debug: unset git_dir start @ Wed, Sep  6, 2017 10:12:28 PM
remote: Debug: unset git_dir end @ Wed, Sep  6, 2017 10:12:28 PM
remote: Debug: git pull start @ Wed, Sep  6, 2017 10:12:28 PM
remote: From //liveserver/GIT/repos/ThisProject
remote:  * branch              master     -> FETCH_HEAD
remote:    6434be6e..f6c6e04d  master     -> origin/master
remote: Updating 6434be6e..f6c6e04d
remote: Fast-forward
remote:  applications/the_changed_file.php | 2 +-
remote:  1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
remote: Debug: git pull end @ Wed, Sep  6, 2017 10:13:14 PM
remote: Done!
To //liveserver/GIT/repos/ThisProject.git
   6434be6e..f6c6e04d  master -> master
```

We're completely stumped on how we can get this to speed up to near the speed of how long it takes when running git pull from the live server directly. What could we do to fix this?

We are using Git Bash on Windows Server on both our dev and live servers.

Comment: What's the hooks your used for live server, is it post-receive  hook? And can you show the script of the hook?

Comment: This is the post-receive hook.... :  

`#!/bin/sh

read oldrev newrev refname
BRANCH=${refname#refs/heads/}

if [ "$BRANCH" == "master" ];
then
 cd //liveserver/SMBWindowsShare/ThisProject
 unset GIT_DIR
 echo Debug: git pull start @ "$(date)"
 git pull origin master   # This is what takes 45+ seconds
 echo Debug: git pull end @ "$(date)"
 echo Done!
fi
exit;`

Comment: I added an answer to change part of the post-receive hook script (to instead `unset GIT_DIT` and `git pull origin master`). You can have a try and check if it take fewer seconds.

Answer (score 0):

> Our problem is, that git hook takes approximately 45 seconds to do a git pull from the live server, but when we manually do a git pull on the live server it is nearly instantaneous.

Make sure your hook is saving the environment variables it has when it is executed in a text file

```
#!/bin/bash
env>envs.txt
```

And compare those with the one you are seeing when you are executing yourself the command on the server:

```
set>envs2.txt
```

Do the same for the `git config -l` in both cases.

Maybe the difference in the PATH or a git configuration used would explain why it is so slow in one case but not the other.

Also make sure to use the [latest Git for Windows available](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.14.1.windows.1).

---

> Our problem is, that git hook takes approximately 45 seconds to do a git pull from the live server, but when we manually do a git pull on the live server it is nearly instantaneous.

```
cd //liveserver/SMBWindowsShare/ThisProject 
unset GIT_DIR 
git pull origin master
```

There is a big difference between doing git operation through a shared drive, and doing them on locally on the server.

It would be best if you could instead leave a flag (like write a tmp file) which would then be picked up by a process running on the remote server itself: each time it sees that tmp files, it deletes it, does the git pull and write another tmp file that you own hook can wait for.
That way, the pull process is done directly on the server (no remote lag involved)

Comment: The only difference is that `http.sslbackend=schannel` appears on the dev server and does not appear on the live server.  Everything else is identical

Comment: @kenneth OK. I have edited my answer with a possible alternative.

Comment: I get what you're saying that it's not a local pull so it will have lag, but when I run that same exact command to pull from the dev server to live (on the live server where the git hook lives), it's nearly instantaneous.  So it's definitely not network lag.

Comment: @kenneth a different network lag, then: an SMB share is very slow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12095852/git-is-doing-very-slow-commits-on-a-samba-share-what-can-i-do-to-speed-it-up, https://superuser.com/a/560818/141, https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/issues/306#issuecomment-293992750

Answer (score 0):

To apply the changes from live server to development server after changes are pushed to live server, you can change part of post-receive hook script which meet the condition `"$BRANCH" == "master"` under if condition. The changed part as below:

```
git --work-tree=/path/to/development/server --git-dir=/path/to/live/server pull origin master
```

**Note:** if the development server and live has un-related histories, you can use `git checkout -f` instead.